# Nestjs - pipeline can't access user

Tags: nestjs

I am using a pipeline to decrypt the post data, and every user have a key.

so i am doing it as injectable and trying to inject request

```
@Injectable()
export class DecryptDataPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private applicationUsersService: ApplicationUsersService,
    private userKeysService: UserKeysService,
    @Req() private request,
  ) {}

  ...
}
```

this code always return an error, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject the `Request` object you need to use [`@Inject(REQUEST)`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider). `@Req()` is a parameter decorator for controller methods, not for general use in constructors.